# Using INSERT INTO with association in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, insert-into

Let's say I have two tables. Is there a way to insert rows into both simultaneously? When I had 1 table I could simply do

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('Tom','Prats','tom@tomprats.com'), ('Tim', 'Prats', tim@tomprats.com);
```

If I now have 1 table that stores email, and an associated table that stores first and last name, how do I insert both at once? Keeping in mind I'm importing a lot of data.

`Table "users"
       Column        |     Type      | Modifiers
---------------------+---------------+-----------
 id                  | character(36) | not null
 email               | text          |
Indexes:
    "pk_users" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_users_attributes" FOREIGN KEY (attributes_id) REFERENCES user_attributes(id)`

`Table "user_attributes"
     Column      |     Type      | Modifiers
-----------------+---------------+-----------
 id              | character(36) | not null
 first_name      | text          |
 last_name       | text          |
Indexes:
    "pk_user_attributes" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "users" CONSTRAINT "fk_users_attributes" FOREIGN KEY (attributes_id) REFERENCES user_attributes(id)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this only by insert.

If you must do this in a single line the best way to do it is to write a short function that will make 2 inserts. This will result in a single transaction per call(if this was the main problem).

You can also use [Data-Modifying Statements in WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

Comment: I'm importing data from a separate application, so I don't think `WITH` would help, but this did help me realize I could generate the primary key for both tables beforehand so they would be related when I insert them separately